# Problem connecting an event to dynamically added dom element with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am having a problem with connecting a click event to a dynamically added dom element. I add a new dom element like this:

```
var link = dojo.create("a",{
                      className: "deleteDnd",
                      innerHTML: "Delete"
                    },this.domNode,"first");
```

I would now like to add a click event to this dynamically added link, however I have tried to add the event numerous times but it fails. I am able to connect the event using firebug after the element has been appended. Is there a way to connect the event whilst creating the element something like :

```
var link = dojo.create("a",{
                      className: "deleteDnd",
                      innerHTML: "Delete"
                    },this.domNode,"first");
dojo.event.connect(link, "onclick", function(node, index, nodelist){
                        console.log("was clicked");

                    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: the version I am using is 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `dojo.event.connect` doesn't exist anymore in the newer versions of Dojo. Try using just `dojo.connect` instead.

```
dojo.connect(link, "onclick", function(node, index, nodelist){
        console.log("was clicked");
        console.log(node, index, nodelist); // Only first argument is defined
    });
```

You'll also notice that the link's event handler function will only get one argument (the event), not node, index and nodeList.